# What objects are in JProfiler 9.2 "CMS Old Gen" Memory Pool?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jprofiler

Using JProfiler 9.2, how can I see which Objects are in the memory pool "CMS Old Gen"?

Answer (score 0):

That information is unfortunately not provided by the JVM, only the statistocs are provided by the GC.